# Is there an existing hack to play audio on someone’s iphone as a prank?

Tags: iphone, wifi, hacking, memory-leak

I have this old iPhone 5c which I believe isn’t supported anymore, doesn’t get updates, leaving it’s security vulnerable, I imagine.

This morning while browsing a distorted voice came from the 5c. It wasn’t Siri, a phone call, or a video autoplaying. It isn’t a physical malfunction on behalf of the speaker, it was working fine. It was a creepy distorted voice from the 5c’s speaker, which I think said something ominous like “want to play a game?” but it could just be my wild imagination.

Turned the thing off and nothing else happened so far. Some other details I should note:

- I have a newer phone which I use for anything sensitive; the 5c doesn’t have a SIM card and I logged out of my apple ID a while ago. I just use this as a backup for browsing and travel photos. My new phone has also not done anything creepy atm.
- I have never jailbroken this 5c.
- Might’ve clicked an ad/went to a weird site on accident a few days ago.

So I just want to ask:

- Is there an existing hack that allows someone to do this? When I tried researching, all I found was info on a smart speaker hack and just general malfunctions.
- If a hack exists, can it only be done with physical access to the device, or over Wifi?
- Should I be concerned about my personal information? While no information/logins of importance would be inputted into the phone directly, I am worried about the possibility of them finding my Wifi password from memory.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). Just a heads up though, this site is a Q&A site and it typically works best when each question is basically a single question. At present, your question is really asking multiple questions and does risk being flagged as such. Reading [how to ask a question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) may improve your chances of getting a good answer.

Comment: "[Shall we play a game?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KXzNo0vR_dU)" is the iconic question posed by the synthesized voice of WOPR in the movie "[War Games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WarGames)" with Matthew Broderick and Ally Sheedy. It is/was possible to use iTunes to create a ring-tone that could be used for phone calls as well as alerts. Perhaps this was the method used to have this come from the iPhone, either as a phone call ring or an alert, such as a calendar alarm.